# How to create a transition table from multiple sequences?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a transition table from multiple sequences of discrete states:

```
sequence1 = [0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1, 4]
sequence2 = [1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3]
...
```

I can create a transition table from a single sequence using pandas.crosstab function:

```
import pandas as pd
transitions = pd.crosstab(pd.Series(sequence1[1:],name='Next'),
            pd.Series(sequence1[:-1],name='Current'),normalize=1)
```

How can I create the transition table from multiple sequences? (Combining them into a single long list introduces false transitions between the end of one sequence and the beginning of the next.)

Edit: The current output looks like this, giving the probability for each transition within sequence1:

```
>>> transitions
Current     0         1         2    3    4    5
Next                                        
1         1.0  0.000000  0.666667  0.0  0.0  0.0
2         0.0  0.333333  0.000000  0.0  0.0  1.0
3         0.0  0.333333  0.333333  0.0  0.0  0.0
4         0.0  0.333333  0.000000  0.5  0.0  0.0
5         0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.5  1.0  0.0
```

I want the same output format but the probabilities reflecting multiple input sequences.

Comment: can you paste the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resulting transition DataFrame should be a **square** array,
including **all** your states, but your result isn't (it has
no row for *"0"* state).

I also assume that all your sequences contain consecutive numbers
as state names, without "gaps".

My solution is even more general, it works for a list containing
an arbitrary number of source sequences:

```
def transitions(allSeq):
    # Size of the transition array
    n = max([ max(s) for s in allSeq ]) + 1
    # Transition array, initially empty
    arr = np.zeros((n,n), dtype=int)
    for s in allSeq:
        ind = (s[1:], s[:-1])  # Indices of elements for existing transitions
        arr[ind] += 1          # Add existing transitions
    # Normalize by columns and return as a DataFrame
    return pd.DataFrame(arr / arr.sum(axis=0)).rename_axis(index='Next', columns='Current')
```

Note that `arr / arr.sum(axis=0)` performs column normalization, at the
*Numpy* level, and then the result is converted into a DataFrame.

When you call it, passing a list of your sequences:

```
res = transitions([sequence1, sequence2])
```

the result is:

```
Current    0         1         2         3         4    5
Next                                                     
0        0.0  0.142857  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.0
1        1.0  0.142857  0.666667  0.000000  0.000000  0.0
2        0.0  0.285714  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  1.0
3        0.0  0.285714  0.333333  0.000000  0.333333  0.0
4        0.0  0.142857  0.000000  0.666667  0.333333  0.0
5        0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.333333  0.333333  0.0
```

Of course, there can be more than 2 source sequences.

Comment: This allows me to use the type of input I want, but I do want to preserve the normalization to get the probability of each transition since I am using this to create a Markov chain.